# Como incluir arquivos do Bootstrap em um tema?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wordpress

Estou tentando incluir a responsividade do Bootstrap no Wordpress, eu tentei via CDN e entre alguns outros métodos mas funciona meio que parcial. Por exemplo: Se eu aplicar classes tipo `container`, `row`, um botão com classe `alert` funciona, mas, quando eu tento fazer um `navbar` *"collapsavel"* o menu fica todo deformado e sem estilização (mesmo pegando código pronto no site do Bootstrap).

Criei os arquivos *header, index, sidebar, footer, functions, style* e não andei nada ainda porque não consigo fazer essa coisa funcionar direito.

pasta do arquivo de como estou fazendo com print de como fica o menu . ele nao pega o estilo e nem a responsividade

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1FJOnA41Xp6VjdzRDlKRWRRRUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Outro `.css` está passando "por cima" do bootstrap. No HTML, qualquer `.css` que vier depois OU tiver o sufixo `!important` após sua propriedade irá ter maior prioridade. Exemplo: o bootstrap aplica todo o CSS dele no `navbar` que você acabou de criar. Porém, ele foi chamado ANTES de um outro `.css` e aí este `.css` retardatário possui as mesmas propriedades CSS do bootstrap, resultado: ele sobrescreverá o bootstrap.

Comment: Algum plugin (ou o próprio tema) podem estar chamando outra versão do bootstrap que você deseja...de toda a forma, use o INSPETOR DE ELEMENTOS do Chrome (F12) para verificar se as propriedades existem e se foram sobrescritas

Comment: galera  nao sei o que acontece, bauxei um tema simples que usa bootstrap mas quando eu copio pro meu sublime nao rola , eu upei a pasta do meu projeto se puderem dar uma olhada eu coloquei um print de como fica o menu , e a responsividade nao rola tbm , nao sei porque.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1FJOnA41Xp6VjdzRDlKRWRRRUU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar também o arquivo JavaScript pois estes componetes dependem de código JavaScript. Coloque depois da sua tag que inclui o `JQuery`.

Exemplo para colocar no `<head>`

```
<script src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
. . .
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/wp-content/themes/xpto/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=3.3.4' type='text/css' media='all'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/themes/xpto/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.3.4'></script>
```

Aqui estou supondo que seu tema se chama `xpto`

Obviamente você pode usar CDN.